# extract subarray value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

MongoDB noob here...

I have a collection as follows...

```
    > db.students.find({_id:22},{scores:[{type:'exam'}]}).pretty()
    {
        "_id" : 22,
        "scores" : [
            {
                "type" : "exam",
                "score" : 75.04996547553947
            },
            {
                "type" : "quiz",
                "score" : 10.23046475899236
            },
            {
                "type" : "homework",
                "score" : 96.72520512117761
            },
            {
                "type" : "homework",
                "score" : 6.488940333376703
            }
        ]
    }
```

how do I display only the quiz score via mongo shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB extract only the selected item in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have some syntax in your original example which probably isn't doing what you expect .. that is, it looks like your intent was to only match scores for a specific type ('exam' in your example, 'quiz' by your description).

Below are some examples using the MongoDB 2.2 shell.

#### `$elemMatch` projection

You can use the [$elemMatch projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) to return the first matching element in an array:

```
db.students.find(
    // Search criteria
    { '_id': 22 },

    // Projection
    { _id: 0, scores: { $elemMatch: { type: 'exam' } }}
)
```

The result will be the matching element of the array for each document, eg:

```
{ "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 75.04996547553947 } ] }
```

#### Aggregation Framework

If you want to display more than one matching value or reshape the result document instead of returning the full matching array element, you can use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/):

```
db.students.aggregate(
    // Initial document match (uses index, if a suitable one is available)
    { $match: {
        '_id': 22, 'scores.type' : 'exam'
    }},

    // Convert embedded array into stream of documents
    { $unwind: '$scores' },

    // Only match scores of interest from the subarray
    { $match: {
        'scores.type' : 'exam'
    }},

    // Note: Could add a `$group` by _id here if multiple matches are expected

    // Final projection: exclude fields with 0, include fields with 1
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        score: "$scores.score"
    }}
)
```

The result in this case includes would be:

```
{ "result" : [ { "score" : 75.04996547553947 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: What Stennie said, he ******* built the database.

Comment: By $elemMatch, what if I want two elements **type: 'exam'** and **type : 'quiz'** ? plz reply