# get element of array which belong to a array in mongodb by index

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

For example, the mongo document as follows:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxx"),
    "array": [
        0,
        1,
        [2, 3],
        4
    ]
}
```

Is there a method to get the `2` from the document?

Comment: I imagine the solution would be very close to the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452745/extract-subarray-value-in-mongodb

Comment: By `get the 2` you mean "find the documents that has a 2 there" or "select only the 2 from the document in the query"? What is the context that you need it? is it a batch? how many data? there might be simple solutions but they are not so fast.

Comment: @AmiramKorach It means select only 3 from the document. There are 3000+ records.

Comment: Where are you trying to do it? node? mongo shell?

Comment: @AmiramKorach python with pymongo

Comment: If you have only 3000 records and you can wait for the answer, you can do a simple forEach, but I don't know if you can do it with pymongo or you have to use the shell.